# Trying to Save and Fetch data using Firebase but receiving this Error

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4.2

I ma trying to save data on firebase and then Fetching data from that data base but seeing this Error.I have tried many links but not found any help? Thanks Advance...

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var databaseRefer: DatabaseReference!
 var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    databaseRefer = Database.database().reference()
    databaseRefer.child("name").childByAutoId().setValue("England")
   databaseRefer.child("name").childByAutoId().setValue("Pakistan")

    DatabaseHandle = 
     databaseRefer.child("name").observe(.childAdded, with: { 
         (data) in
        let name = (data.value as? String)
        debugPrint(name)
    })
}



Geting this Error at this line...

DatabaseHandle = databaseRefer.child("name").observe(.childAdded, 
    with: { (data) in
        let name = (data.value as? String)
        debugPrint(name)
    })
```

Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'DatabaseHandle.Type' 
   (aka 'UInt.Type')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fetching your data the following way :

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "YOUR_CHILD_NAME")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if !snapshot.exists() { return }
    print("DATA RECEIVED FROM FIREBASE!!!")
    print(snapshot.value)
}
```